# How would you edit `/etc/crontab` and files under `/etc/cron.d/?

Tags: cron

In my `/etc/crontab`

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

We can use crontab to edit a user-defined crontab files under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`, but can't use the same way to edit `/etc/crontab` or files under `/etc/cron.d/`. Are they supposed to be edited? If yes, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your preferred editor. `nano` and `vim` are good editors. The 6th field is the username under which the entry should run.

**EDIT:**

I have a BSD 4.2 box. I have to export the editor before editing the crontab file on it.

```
EDITOR=vi
export EDITOR
crontab -e
```