# Crontab changes not working

Tags: linux, cron, suse

I recently made some changes to my crontab, added some new entries and activated one disabled (commented) entry. However, the new changes that I made were not triggered and the crontab functioned as it was in the previous state, although the crontab shows the changes made to it.

One more thing, i also edited the crontab file of root user in my "/var/spool/cron" folder. I think it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit a crontab file, *always* use `crontab -e`.  If you want to edit the crontab of the root user, use `sudo crontab -e`.

Changing the files under the crontab spool directory is definitely not advised.  Editing via `crontab -e` additionally informs the cron daemon that the crontab needs to be re-read.  This may not otherwise happen.

Related:

- [Can I manually create and edit `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/t` without `crontab -e`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478968)

Comment: So now what do I have do? I should also mention that I edited the crontab with "crontab -e" afterwards. Will this be enough for the changes to take effect?

Comment: @FaisalAbbas Editing the crontab with `crontab -e` will ensure that the changes take effect. If you have any errors in the crontab, then this may cause the jobs to fail (and an error message to be emailed to the owner of the crontab), but you never showed what your crontab looked like so I couldn't really comment on that.

Comment: I edited the crontab with "crontab -e" and the job worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To apply changes to `/etc/crontab` file you need to edit it via console editor, for example

```shell
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

Changes must be applied automatically without any reloading crond. I suppose that you changed `crontab` on local machine and then moved it to server.